# why object prototype shows up as html attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, prototype

I did this (using version mootools-core-1.4.5.js)

```
Object.prototype.walkRecursive = function(callable, bindable) {
var p, val, retVal, _bind;

_bind = (typeof bindable === 'object') ? bindable : this;
for (p in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if (!(this[p] instanceof Object)) {
            if (typeof callable === 'function')
            {
                retVal = callable.call(_bind, p, this[p]);
                if (typeof retVal !== 'undefined')
                {
                    this[p] = retVal;
                }
            }
            else {
                throw "Podaj funkcje jako drugi argument";
            }
        } else if (this[p] instanceof Object) {
            this[p].walkRecursive(callable, bindable);
        }
    }
}
return this;
};
```

Then

```
    var navigationEl = new Element('div', {
        'class' : 'wcag-navigation'
    }).inject(this._element);
```

And when I check how this._wcagButton.pausePlay HTML element looks like in Chrome Developer Tools looks like, I got:

[image: strange html attribute]

Same thing happens when I use Mootools' **implement**:

```
 Object.implement({walkRecursive :function(callable, bindable) {....}.protect()});
```

How come? Please help, how to cope with this issue

**Example of use**

```
var data = [
{
    id: 0, 
    name: 'Template 0', 
    subComponents: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Template 1', subItems:[
            {id: 2, name: 'Template 2', subComponents:[
                {id: 3, name: 'Template 3'}
            ], 
             subItems: [
                 {id: 4, name: 'Template 4',},
                 {id: '42'}
             ]
            }
        ]}
    ]}
];

var bindMe = {
  nothing:'special'
}

data.walkRecursive(function(key,value){
if(key === 'name')
{
    return value+' '+this.nothing;
}
},bindMe)
```

Comment: what is the function `walkRecursive` supposed to do and where do you call it ?

Comment: It should walk recursively on every item of object and if that item is object it should go deeper. It should call callback function passed via 'callable' parameter with this signature: function(key,value){}. If that callback returns something it should override original value.
I would like to call it when I want to make new instance of Mootools class and set special options with object [type Object]

Comment: Can you show example of the call ? something like `navigationEl.walkRecursive();` ?

Comment: I added example of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

er. Although you `can` extend `Object`, it is still strongly considered a bad practice to do so since in JavaScript, everything inherits from that Type. To see why you should not be doing that - http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/ or google `extending object prototype is verboten` - plenty of answers on the subject. As you can see yourself, what you added is enumerable.

If you only care about modern JavaScript, you can use `defineProperty` to set it as `enumerable: false`.

In order to be able to work with Objects easier in MooTools, there used to be a thing called `Hash` - http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Native/Hash - which is now available in compat MooTools builds - otherwise, it has been deprecated for 1.4.x - see http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object#Deprecated-Functions:Hash

You can just use Object to host methods and call them on objects, this is what http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object does.

Here is your code converted: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ4Yh/3/

```
Object.extend({
    walkRecursive: function (object, callable, bindable) {
        var p, val, retVal, _bind;

        // this next bit is unsafe, 'object' also returned for Date or Array constructor
        _bind = (typeof bindable === 'object') ? bindable : object;
        for (p in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                if (!(object[p] instanceof Object)) {
                    if (typeof callable === 'function') {
                        retVal = callable.call(_bind, p, object[p]);
                        if (typeof retVal !== 'undefined') {
                            object[p] = retVal;
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw "Podaj funkcje jako drugi argument";
                    }
                    //also unsafe instanceof. 
                } else if (object[p] instanceof Object) {
                    // shouldn't you use _bind, not bindable?
                    Object.walkRecursive(object[p], callable, bindable);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
});


var data = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Template 0',
    subComponents: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Template 1',
        subItems: [{
            id: 2,
            name: 'Template 2',
            subComponents: [{
                id: 3,
                name: 'Template 3'
            }],
            subItems: [{
                id: 4,
                name: 'Template 4',
            }, {
                id: '42'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

var bindMe = {
    nothing: 'special'
};

Object.walkRecursive(data, function(key, value){
    if (key === 'name'){
        return value + ' ' + this.nothing;
    }
}, bindMe);

console.log(data);

// unsafe because.
console.log(new Date() instanceof Object, [] instanceof Object, function(){} instanceof Object);

// eg safer isObject
var isObject = function(what){
    return {}.toString.call(what).slice(8, -1) === 'Object';
};

console.log(isObject(new Date()), isObject([]), isObject(function(){}), isObject({}));
```

this includes some examples of the unsafe checks and how to do them differently to ensure correct logic.

in any case--in case you were wondering--a DOM element also returns an Element Object, hence you can see what you've added.

some people say it's OK to use this if you iterate via `hasOwnProperty` but it is not. eg a dictionary object:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
obj.name = 'template 0';

for (var k in obj){
    console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty[k]); // throws, no method hasOwnProperty
    // if you omit hasOwnProperty here, you break jslint and jshint, confusing... 
}
```

of course, you can fix it by using:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
obj.name = 'template 0';

var hasOwnProperty = {}.hasOwnProperty;

for (var k in obj){
    console.log(k, hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k));
}
```

etc etc - but it makes your code base way too defensive just because of a style choice and a simple convenience that you really don't need.

Comment: nice answer as always - can you explain why it's good that in your code sample: `console.log(isObject(new Date()), isObject([]), isObject(function(){}), isObject({}));` date,array and function are not consider as instanceof object ?

Comment: the context. it's when you want to work with actual objects and not objects derived from Object types. if one of the properties is say, a regex or date, it may also try to walk it...

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I have to take some time to get it, and read about extending Object's prototype. First of all, I don't get it, because if I use `new Element` with options in object I thought that Element's constructor uses `hasOwnProperty` to get rid of inherited properties.

Comment: Because EVERYTHING inherits from Object: http://jsfiddle.net/gDzhB/ but in old IE, Element.prototype is read only-ish. MooTools gets around that by copying from Element.prototype onto Elements. see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L266-L276 - this uses `Object.append`, https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L377-L383 -> which does NOT use `hasOwnProperty` because it needs to be fast and extending Object proto is not allowed by convention...